# Why do RDS read replicas need automated backup turned on for source DB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

The [documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReadRepl.html) says "When creating a Read Replica, there are a few things to consider. First, you must enable automatic backups on the source DB instance by setting the backup retention period to a value other than 0."

Why would backup be needed for read replicas? Is it for avoiding the I/O impact on source DB in cases like when a new read replica is created or the read replica needs to "catch-up" after a maintenance window?